# ¿Por qué me da HTTP ERROR 500 al intentar acceder a Wordpress en localhost?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

Estaba migrando esta mañana mi sitio `Wordpress` a un servidor local para hacer pruebas, pero me he encontrado con el siguiente problema. Cuando intento acceder escribiendo en el navegador **localhost** me sale este error:

> *Esta página no funciona
>   La página **localhost** no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
>   **HTTP ERROR 500***

El servidor que estoy usando es `IIS`, he instalado `mysql` y `php` también y me funcionaba todo bien, estaba probando con una página sencilla **index.html** y con el `phpmyadmin` y podía ver la página y acceder al `phpmyadmin` a través de **localhost/phpmyadmin**, pero al copiar todas las carpetas y cosas de `wordpress` me ha dejado de funcionar, me muestra ese error y no puedo ni siquiera entrar al `phpmyadmin`.

¿Que ha pasado y como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias

Adjunto imagen del error:
[image: Error que me da al acceder]

Comment: Gracias, ya lo he editado.

Answer (score 1):

creo que el problema que tienes se debe a que en la base de datos los enlaces figuran como dominioantuguio.com/ruta entonces tienes que sustituir el dominio por localhost en caso de querer usarlo en el pc de forma local y si es en otro dominio cambiarlo por el nombre del dominio nuevo!

Comment: En la base de datos he cambiado el dominio por localhost, en wp-options en siteurl he puesto http://localhost

Comment: Vale mira también en el archivo HTCACCESS

Comment: Que debo de mirar en el HTCACCESS? El caso es que lo que me parece muy raro, es que el PHPMYADMIN que me estaba funcionando bien y podía acceder a él, despues de copiar los archivos y carpetas de Wordpress me ha dejado de funcionar tambien... @Peter

Comment: Las rutas a ver si están bien, revisa el archivo también config.php creo que era, ya que ahí también tienes que sustituir cosas probablemente.

Comment: Sí, en HTCACCESS están bien y en wp-config.php he cambiado los datos de acceso a la base de datos pero sigue sin funcionar, me sale el mismo error. Voy a adjuntar una captura a el mensaje principal mostrando el error.

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido avanzar algo, ahora casi me carga la página me ha salido en el titulo de la pestaña el titulo de página pero posteriormente me ha dado este error y no se ha cargado. Ahora al PhpMyAdmin si que me deja acceder.

> No se puede acceder a este sitio web
>   La página localhost ha rechazado la conexión.
>   Prueba a:
>
> Comprobar la conexión
>   Comprobar el proxy y el cortafuegos
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Que me decis?

Gracias!